# Using Cloud SQL server as source for scribe

Tags: sql-server, cloud, scribe-workbench

I am planning to use scribe insight for integration. I have used SQL server with scribe before. But they were related to the same Active directory. But this time my source will be a SQL server hosted in the cloud.

1. Is it really possible to use a cloud based SQL server as a source?
2. What kind of adapter should I use?

Comment: wherever the database is you are going to connect to it via a connectionstring. as long as the client can connect to it , it should be fine. if at all you are using MS azure cloud then may be you should try with Sql database on a VM which is going to be almost same as the on premises one. on the AD part you would have to do a AD sync from on prem to azure so that you can connect to the db using Active directory based authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your response Aravind, you are right this is possible as  long as the connection string is correct. However this design was scrapped due to a long list of reasons! Thank you again